# In which table will be foreign key if the relation in two tables is many to one i.e. from 1st table (many ) to second table(one)

Tags: sql

In which table will be foreign key if the relation in two tables is many to one i.e. from 1st table (many ) to second table(one).

Answer (score 0):

The 1st table.  What do I win??!

Comment: Nothing, unless your correct confusion between relation and relationship!

Comment: The confusion is in the value of the homework when it is delegated.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key will be in the first table i.e. your many table.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys are in tables that reference other tables, so in your case it will be in "many"-table. Don't be fooled by cardinality - there can be foreign key defined in 1:1 relationship.